# IIF in Table Definition resolving to CASE WHEN

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case-when, iif

I am running SQL Server 2012 and find that by using `IIF` in a table definition, the server then resolved the table definition as a `CASE WHEN` statement.

T_TABLE.sql

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_TABLE] (
    [ID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [FLG] AS (IIF ([COL1] = [COL2] AND [STATUS] <> 'FAIL', 1, 0)),
    [COL1] INT NULL,
    [COL2] INT NULL,
    [STATUS] VARCHAR (2000) NULL
);
```

After running this code in the database I use SSMS to script the table definition and get the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_TABLE] (
    [ID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [FLG] AS (case when [COL1]=[COL2] AND [STATUS]<>'FAIL' then (1) else (0) end),
    [COL1] INT NULL,
    [COL2] INT NULL,
    [STATUS] VARCHAR (2000) NULL
);
```

This is of course causing issues when running git / schema diffs saying that these two tables are not equal.

Is there a "rule" against using `IIF` over `CASE WHEN`? I've always found the former to be more succinct for creating flags / simple logic rules.

Comment: Just use `CASE`.  It is the ANSI standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IIF` is syntax sugar for making converting from MSAccess to SQL Server easier.  It's pretty clear from the results you are showing that SQL Server is simply converting the `IIF` you entered to the more generalized and ANSI compatible `CASE WHEN`construction when it parses it.  I would never recommend using `IIF` other than for portability to/from MS Access.

You'll find that SQL Server will often rewrites computed columns and check constraints to simplify gratuitous parenthesis and things like that to a standardized form, so that when you script it out of SSMS it may not be identical to what you put in your DDL.  This is apparently another one of those cases.